# Cooper pairs and superconductivity

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, superconductivity

This might be a dumb series of questions, because I'm not a theoretical or condensed matter physicist.

If there was a method of pairing all electrons before entering a semiconductor, would you essentially have a cheat code to turn any semiconductor into a superconductor, or does the lattice of semiconductors vibrate too much that pairs would still bump into it, disengaging the pairs, and losing energy to heat?

If the latter is true, is this because the energy required to maintain and disengage entanglement is low?

If the former may be true, would energy in the transmission of electrons still be lost due to the effort required to establish electron pairs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, there is nothing special about the lattice of a semiconductor that would prevent it to "host" Cooper pairs.

The process that you describe of "pairing all electrons before entering [your preferred material here]" is called proximity effect. You just juxtapose a superconductor with another material (generally a non-superconducting metal, but semiconductors and even some insulators work) and the Cooper pairs from the superconductor will "take a walk" inside the other material. For your specific case, just google "proximity superconductivity in semiconductors" and you will find several references. Note that, here, superconductivity is not a property of the semiconducutor and will not survive inside it if you kill superconductivity in your nearby superconductor.

Besides the proximity effect, you can also have semiconductors that can show a superconducting transition by themselves (google "semiconductor superconductivity"). The key here is to dope the semiconductor in order to have a high enough mobile charge density (either electrons in the conduction band or holes in the valence band).

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to the answer perfectly. It's a shame the universe has to be so difficult as to not lets us cheat our way to superconductivity with regular conductive metals.